# How to make C++ program work across compilers

Tags: c++, visual-c++, borland-c++

I wanted to know how I would make my C++ program work across compilers. I wanted to make the program so if it's being compiled with borland it will use the `clrscr()` function otherwise it'd use `system("CLS")`. I've seen code that has done something similar but I couldn't find an explanation of what it does or how it works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

In general, to make a C or C++ program work across multiple compilers you want to confine yourself to standard C or C++ as much as possible. Sometimes you have to use compiler/platform specific functionality, though, and one way to handle that is via the preprocessor.

The [predef](http://predef.sourceforge.net/) project on SourceForge lists a bunch a preprocessor symbols that are defined automatically by various compilers, for various platforms, et cetera. You can use that information to implement what you need, for example:

```
void clearScreen() {
  // __BORLANDC__ is defined by the Borland C++ compiler.
  #ifdef __BORLANDC__
    clrscr();
  #else
    system("cls");
  #endif
}
```

Comment: Don't do conditional compilation inside functions. Foreach version of a command generate the appropriate macro definition for each compiler. Though it seems to be fine for this simple type of command as soon as you do anything more complex the code becomes unreadable. The only thing clearScreen() should do is invoke the macro PLATFORM_CLEAR_SCREEN()

Comment: @Martin - you're advocating putting the majority of the work in the hands of macros? But macros are [evil](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.4)! :)

Answer (score 3):

One easy answer from the top of the head is define your own function calls and then translate it into real calls depending on the compiling parameters (with #ifdef preprocessing definitions - look which values are corresponding to which compiler). 
example:

```
#if defined(__COMPILER_ONE__)
#define ClearScreen() clrscr()
#elif defined(__COMPILER_TWO__)
#define ClearScreen() system("CLS")
#else 
#error "I do not know what to do!"
#endif
```

You would have to create a dedicated header file for this and to include it everywhere, of course.

(Of course you have to substitute **COMPILER_ONE** and **COMPILER_TWO** with relevant definitions :) )

Answer (score 0):

How to make something work across different compilers is simple question which is *very* complex to answer! Your specific query about clearing the screen;

I would attempt it like this, first you have your own function say

```
      void clear_screen();
```

And define it like this:

```
      void clear_screen()
      {
        #ifdef LINUX
           ...

        #eleif MS_WIN

          ...
        #endif
      }
```

Please note I have just guessed what the #define 's are.  This is know as conditional complication,  generally regarded as evil, but containing it in a function reduces the harm a little.

Comment: Conditional compilation regarded as evil?  Hardly.  More like absolutely necessary in all but the most trivial multi-platform projects.

Comment: @PigBen True.  But a mild sort of evil, nonetheless. 'use sparingly' is more accurate but less fun

Comment: evil != not necessary, conditional compilation is a pretty good example of a necessary evil imho

Comment: @PigBen - it's not absolutely necessary to use conditionals that identify the platform, since you can instead include different header files on different platforms by setting different include paths. In this case of course the header file would then either have to define the function, or else you'd have to compile and link different TUs on different platforms.

Comment: @Steve:  Okay, not absolutely necessary.  But given the choice between mucking around with build options Vs. letting the compiler figure it out for you based on a few pre-processor defines, I would choose the latter every time.

Comment: @PigBen: if the differences are small I would, but if each platform is expected to supply a potentially large "portability header" to support the app by declaring various isolation APIs, then I'd make it the responsibility of the porter/integrator to write that (or tweak the default) and put it on the include path (and link path, if there's more to it thatn #defines, typedefs, and inline functions). Compare what you'd do for just `clear_screen` vs what you'd do to implement something like QT...

Answer (score 0):

The way it's typically done is through the magic of the preprocessor or makefiles.  Either way, you hide the implementation details behind a common interface in a header file, such as `void clearscreen()`.  Then in a single source file you can hide the Borland implementation behind #ifdef BORLAND, and similarly for other implementations.  Alternatively, you can put each implementation in a separate source file, and only compile the proper one based on a variable in a makefile.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking compiler macros with the `#ifdef` compiler macro:

```
#ifdef BORLAND
    borland();
#else
    otherCompiler();
#endif
```